# Campos computados usando awk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

soy nuevo en awk.

Tengo un fichero .csv como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero añadir otra columna que contenga la conversión de libras a euros. El valor en libras esta contenido en la columna `cost` y todos los números tienen el carácter del símbolo de la libra delante. Además, el nuevo número en euros deberá contener el símbolo € al final (ejemplo: 500€)

Para hacer la conversión, he hecho lo siguiente:

1. Buscar la conversió libra - euro en Internet: 1.15
2. He realizado lo siguiente:

   ```
   cat test_results.csv |awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","} ; {substr($9,2)} ; {$10 = $9 * 1.15} ; {print $10}'
   ```

- { FS = ","}: Separador del fichero ","
- {substr($9,2)}: Quitamos el símbolo de la libra del número para poder hacer operaciones.
- {$10 = $9 * 1.15}: Creamos un nuevo campo número 10 que contiene la conversión
- {print $10}: Mostramos el nuevo campo 10 que contiene la conversión

Sin embargo, no funciona. El resultado por pantalla es un 0 para cada linea. Utilizando la propuesta de los comentarios, la salida es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fíjate que [`substr()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) devuelve un contenido que no estás recogiendo. Por lo tanto, `$9` sigue valiendo lo que valía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas multiplicando por el valor original, que al incluir el signo de libras se convierte a un número inválido, resultando en cero.

Al obtener la subcadena debes considerar que el signo de libra ocupa dos bytes, mas uno del espacio entre la coma y el signo de libra, el número a convertir comienza en la posición 4.

```
awk -F, '{print $0", "(NR==1?"euro":substr($9,4)*1.15"€")}' test_results.csv
```

Para el encabezado verifico con el operador ternario (ó if en linea) si es el primer renglón, de lo contrario añadimos el signo de euro.

Comment: Los valores que devuelve estan mal. Son los mismos de la propuesta que ha hecho Adrian en el comentario de arriba.

Comment: @Panri93: Sólo habría que ajustar el segundo argumento del `substr()`. ¿Con cuál codificación se guardó el csv? Para UTF-8 es 4, para 8859 es 3.

Answer (score 2):

No soy experto usando `awk` por lo que igual hay opciones más óptimas. Teniendo en cuenta que el contenido de nuestro csv se encuentra en el fichero: `443412.csv`:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost
1,Audrey Feest, Pagac-Gorczany, Claudine Moakson, 18/02/2019, Passwords, 20/05/2020, none, £11897.96 
2,Audrey Feest, Crooks Inc, Claudine Moakson, 18/02/2019, Passwords, 20/05/2020, none, £2567.87 
3,Audrey Feest, Graham, Claudine Moakson, 18/02/2019, Passwords, 20/05/2020, none, £14271.56
```

- Ejecuta:

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==1 {next}; {print (substr($9, 4) * 1.15"€")}' 443412.csv
```

- Resultado:

```
13681,5
2952,05
16411,6
```

- `-F`: Delimitador. En este caso usamos como delimitador la coma.
- `FNR`: Sería el `record number` o por así decirlo el nùmero de línea. En caso de que sea la primera avanzamos a la siguiente..
- `substr` : Devuelve la subcadena de una cadena dependiendo de la posición que insertes.

Comment: La conversión que me está dando está mal. Los valores que devuelve son: 1032.65,78.0505 i 312.294.

Comment: Mmm. No entiendo. Eso es el resultado de multiplicar por 1.15 c/u de los datos que es lo que requerías. Por ejemplo el primer dato: `11896.96*1.15 = 13681.503999999997`.

Comment: No lo sé. Copiando la propuesta, el resultado obtenido es el que he puesto en el comentario. Voy a añadirlo en el post.

Comment: Si te fijas, está cogiendo mal el valor. En vez de coger, 11897.96 está haciendo: 897.96 * 1.15 = 1032.65 o 67.87 * 1.15 = 78.05. He cambiado y lo he dejado como lo tenia. Así funciona.

Comment: Mejor colocar datos en texto en lugar de imágenes, de esta manera ya nos basamos en tus datos. Porque según los datos que tengo en el ejemplo que he mostrado está bien. Mejor usar datos ya existentes tuyos.